# Inconveniente con función SizeOf en C#:

Tags: c#, c++

Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien, necesito pedirles el favor con el siguiente inconveniente:
Tengo el siguiente código en C++:

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int edades[] = {1,2,9,8,16,32,9,50,36,20,1,87};
    int limite = (sizeof(edades)/sizeof(edades[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < limite; i++)
    {
            cout<<edades[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

El cual imprime de modo adecuado las edades.
Pero ahora tengo este código en C#:

```
using System;
//using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EdadVectores
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] edades = new int[] {1, 2, 9, 8, 16, 32, 9, 50, 36, 20, 1, 87 };
            int limite = (sizeof(edades)/sizeof(edades[0]));
          
            for (int i = 0; i < limite; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(edades[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y me muestra error en la línea :

```
 int limite = (sizeof(edades)/sizeof(edades[0]));
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

```
( Variablelocal) int[] edades



 IDE0047: Los paréntesis se pueden quitar
    CS0233:"edades" no tiene un tamaño predefinido, por tanto, sizeof se puede usar en un contexto no seguro
    CS0118: ‘edades’ es variable pero se usa como tipo

De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar
```

Comment: Simplemente haces `for (int i = 0; i < edades.Length; i++)` o `foreach(var e in edades)`

Comment: @Yussef y porque no puede usar la variable limite?

Comment: si podes.. pero no tiene sentido.. c# no tiene nada que ver con c++ en ese sentido.. una matriz ya sabe su tamaño, y tiene sus funciones para saberlo.. no tenes que andar contando posiciones de memoria.. porque ademas, usa la memoria de otra forma...

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ limite es el largo del array, es calculado a partir de la cantidad de bytes del array dividido por la cantidad de bytes que pesa el primer elemento (que siempre es 4 porque es un `int`). En C# el sizeof funciona solo para tipos, por lo que no hay conversión directa a este código. Entonces lo más cercano es hacer `int limite = Buffer.ByteLength(edades) / sizeof(int);` y además hay que cambiar la configuración de compilación para que acepte código no seguro. Ahora todo esto para obtener el largo del array que se obtiene simplemente con `edades.Length`

Comment: @Yussef ah bueno gracias

Comment: Respuesta optima gran oprte!.

Answer (score 3):

En C# también existen punteros y [`sizeof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof) pero solo se pueden usar en [entornos no seguros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe).

Por entornos no seguros se refiere a que el código esté en un bloque `unsafe`. Por ejemplo:

```
unsafe
{
    Console.WriteLine(sizeof(int));
}
```

C# está pensado para ser un lenguaje de alto nivel, de modo que no necesites preocuparte de cosas como el manejo de memoria y ser más seguro, evitando el uso de punteros.

A diferencia de C++ que no hay una documentación oficial sino sitios hechos por la comunidad que sirven de referencia, C# sí [tiene una](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/) elaborada por sus creadores.

Puedes consultarla y revisar que [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array) tiene varias funciones y propiedades útiles. La que te interesa es [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length#system-array-length), para averiguar el número de elementos del arreglo.